# How do I subtract from an array and an user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Grok Learning for this code. I have to do something like:

> Weather report
>
> Write a program that asks the user when it rained this week, and then tells them how many days were rain free.

An interaction with your program should look like this:

> Which days had rain? Monday Tuesday Wednesday
>
> Number of days without rain: 4
> ​

Or like this:

> Which days had rain? Thurs
>
> Number of days without rain: 6
> ​

You don't need to check whether the user's input makes sense (i.e. whether they have entered valid days of the week).

This is my current code:

```
day = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
day1 = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
days = input("Which days had rain? ")
for days in day:
  count = days - day
print("Number of days without rain: " + str(len(day)) + count)
```

I'm not sure how this will work, because I want to minus the 'day' with 'days' and print out how much is left as an integer. I'm confused. Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that when you ask the user for input, you are going to get a string. So, if you input something like this: Monday Tuesday hotdog, then your days variable will look like this:

`"Monday Tuesday hotdog"`

So, as you said, you don't care what the input is, as long as you can get how many days. Which implies a number. Therefore, you want to get the length of that string. Or in other words, how many words in the string. Which you can simply get like this:

```
len(days.split())
```

So, now you have how many days. All you have to do is simply subtract:

```
7 - len(days.split())
```

So, your code can simply be made as such:

```
days = input("Which days had rain? ")
print("Number of days without rain: {}".format(7 - len(days.split())))
```

Demo:

```
Which days had rain? m w f s
Number of days without rain: 3
```

Or:

```
Which days had rain? Monday Thursday
Number of days without rain: 5
```

Comment: Does hotdog count as a day in this?

Comment: Yes. I used hotdog as a way to further explain that it doesn't matter what you enter as specified by the OP. As long as it is a word to provide a count for number of days.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let `day` is `list` of possible days

```
day = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
```

Then, you should take input:

```
 days = raw_input("Which days had rain? ")
```

As, you can have multiple days in input, you should `split` them.

```
input_list = days.split()
```

Now have to count how many of your `input` are in `days` list? How?

```
count=0  # counts the number of valid input days 
for input in input_list:  # insures you are checking all the inputs one by one
    if any(input in day for day in days): # check if input exists in the `days` list.
        count+=1

print len(days)-count
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm using python 3. But I understand how it would  work and be structured.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check whether the user's input makes sense (i.e. whether they have entered valid days of the week).
I solved it like this

```
rainyDays = input("Which days had rain? ")
sepDay = rainyDays.split(' ')

for i in sepDay:
    indexOfDays = sepDay.index(i)
    x = 6 - indexOfDays
    if rainyDays == "":
        x = 7 - indexOfDays
print("Number of days without rain: " + str(x))
```

Result

Which days had rain? Monday Tuesday Wednesday anyDay
Number of days without rain: 3

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

```
data = input('Which days had rain? )
days = data.split()
print('Number of days without rain:', 7 - len(days))
```

That is the sample code for it and easy way.